# Web Api Parameter binding Inconsistent

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

After several hours of googling and attempting to figure this out, I still can't figure this out. The issue is that the "[FromBody] Route input" parameter for the create method will for some reason bind Route.RouteMember[0].Lab to the provided data, but it will set Route.RouteMember[0].RouteMemberType to null. (This will happen for all items in the RouteMember array, not just the first item) Why isn't RouteMemberType bound to the input, but yet the input it will bind to lab? I must admit that I have sometimes seen it bind to a RouteMemberType but with no discernible cause.

**Relevant WebApiConfig**

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

**RouteController**

```
[HttpPost]
public Route Create([FromBody] Route input) {
    UnitOfWork.Routes.Add(input);
    UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    return input;
}
```

**Route**

```
public class Route : BaseModel {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String ShortName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RouteMember> RouteMembers { get; set; }
}
```

**RouteMember**

```
public class RouteMember : BaseModel {
    [ForeignKey("Route")]
    public int RouteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Route Route { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Lab")]
    public int LabId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lab Lab { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RouteMemberType")]
    public int RouteMemberTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual RouteMemberType RouteMemberType { get; set; }
}
```

**Lab**

```
public class Lab : BaseModel {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String ShortName { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Building")]
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
}
```

**RouteMemberType**

```
public class RouteMemberType : BaseModel {
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Request Input**

```
{
"id":0,
"name":"t1",
"shortName":"t1",
"routeMembers":[
    {
        "active":true,
        "labId":11,
        "lab":{
            "$id":"1",
            "building":null,
            "name":"t1a",
            "shortName":"t1a",
            "description":"t1a",
            "buildingId":2,
            "id":11,
            "active":true
        },
        "routeMemberTypeId":1,
        "routeMemberType":{
            "$id":"1",
            "name":"Destintation",
            "id":1,
            "active":true
        }
    },
    {
        "active":true,
        "labId":12,
        "lab":{
            "$id":"2",
            "building":null,
            "name":"t2a",
            "shortName":"t2a",
            "description":"t2a",
            "buildingId":2,
            "id":12,
            "active":true
        },
        "routeMemberTypeId":2,
        "routeMemberType":{
            "$id":"2",
            "name":"Fringe",
            "id":2,
            "active":true
        }
    }
],
"active":true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still have been unable to completely resolve this issue to my satisfaction, it appears in some part to be related to the

```
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

in the WebApiConfig. Turning object references off, allows the RouteMemberTypes to be bound. To work around this issue, I am using PreserveReferencesHandling.None and doing the referential integrity manually. I will update if I find a better solution